# Getting error "Can't read input file" on production server but not locally

Tags: java, scala, image-processing, amazon-s3, javax.imageio

I make a POST to a request with a File included in the request body.

In my method I retrieve this File

```
if(request.body.file("imageFile").getOrElse(null) != null) {
          request.body.file("imageFile").map{ case FilePart(key, name, contentType, content) =>
            try{
              val in:InputStream = new BufferedInputStream(new ByteArrayInputStream(content))
              image = ImageIO.read(in)
            } catch {
              case e => Logger.debug(e.printStackTrace.toString); throw new Exception(e.getMessage)
            }
          }
        }
```

If a File is included in the request body it tries to get it, else it just tries to get a file from S3.

```
else {
   try{
     val in:InputStream = new BufferedInputStream(new ByteArrayInputStream(S3Storage.retrieveS3File("facebook.jpg").content))
     image = ImageIO.read(in)
   } catch {
     case e:IOException => Logger.debug("Failed to retrieve facebook image"); throw new IOException(e.getMessage)
   }
```

All this works fine when I run it on my computer, but when I check in this and test it on the amazon server the `image = ImageIO.read(in)` gives me an error; `Can't read input file!`.

For me this makes no sense since the file is either in the request body or it's grabbed from a S3 bucket.

I've debugged this code and in the production environment there is a file available there when the "read" is done.

Why cannot the file be read from the production environment?

regards

Comment: Wrapping a `ByteArrayInputStream` in a `BufferedInputStream` is pointless, as it's already reading from a buffer (the array). I will only decrease performance.

Comment: When you debug, which one of your `ImageIO.read` do you hit? The one with the uploaded image or the one from Amazon?

Answer (score 0):

One suggestion would be **not to swallow the original exception and stack trace**.
Use constructor `new Exception(message, catchedException)` in your catch blocks.